# Trouble with creating inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm trying to make an inner class(button) inside the class "learn" but I'm getting an error.From my memory the way i'm doing it now used to work for me but now it's giving me an error.Am I doing something wrong? Here is the code:

```
package Lib;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class learn {
Socket s;
PrintWriter pw;
InputStreamReader read;
BufferedReader reader;

 public void setUpNetworking(){
try {
s = new Socket("24.7.31.101",5000);
pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
read = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
reader = new BufferedReader(read);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public class button(){

}
public void go(){
JFrame f  = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
JTextArea messages = new JTextArea();
JTextField userSend = new JTextField();
JButton sending = new JButton("Send");
JScrollPane message = new JScrollPane(messages);



userSend.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,22));
messages.setLineWrap(false);
messages.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
messages.setEditable(false);
message.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
message.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

p.add(message);
p2.add(userSend);
p2.add(sending);

f.add(p,BorderLayout.NORTH);
f.add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));

}
public static void main(String args[]){
learn l = new learn();
l.go();
}

}
```

Comment: And you are not trying to instantiate that class anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**problem:**

```
public class button(){}
```

Wrong format for creating a `class` it should be

```
public class button{}
```

Comment: @noobProgrammer happens all thetime

Answer (score 1):

A class doesn't use parenthesis in its declaration. It should be

```
public class button {
                   ^ no parenthesis here
                   parenthesis are for methods only
}
```